# I cannot extend the express request interface/type

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, inheritance, request

I have extended the request interface that express.js provided to a custom one that want to use but I am getting an error when I type annotate the request object in the request handler with my custom request interface.

the error says

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application<Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(request: Request, response: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>' is missing the following properties from type 'Application<Record<string, any>>': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 63 more.
```

This is my custom request interface file `interfaces/Request.ts`

```
import { Request as ExpressRequest } from "express";
import { User } from "@prisma/client";

interface Request extends ExpressRequest {
  id: string;
  user: User;
}

export default Request;
```

This is one of my request handlers `controllers/auth/login.ts`

```
import { Response } from "express";

import Request from "../../interfaces/Request";

const loginHandler = async (request: Request, response: Response) => {};

export default loginHandler;
```

and this is my auth router `routers/auth.ts`

```
import { Router } from "express";

import loginHandler from "../controllers/auth/login";

const authRouter = Router();

authRouter.get("/login", loginHandler);

export default authRouter;
```

This is my `routers/index.ts` which I use to export all the routers

```
import authRouter from "./auth";

const routers = [
  {
    path: "/auth",
    routeHandler: authRouter,
  },
];

export default routers;
```

This is my main file `server.ts`

```
import express from "express";

// App routers
import routers from "./routers";

const app = express();

const useRouters = () => {
  routers.forEach(({ path, routeHandler }) => {
    app.use(path, routeHandler);
  });
};
useRouters();

const port = process.env.PORT || '3500'

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Those were my files that are related to my custom request interface

**Note:** when I remove my custom request interface annotation and use the express request interface I get no error

Comment: On which of the many calls in your code are you getting this error?

Comment: Well express doesn't supply `.id` and `.user` on its requests, so the TypeError is accurate.